# Google earth plugin api KML

Tags: javascript, sql, kml, google-earth-plugin

Is it possible to getkml of all features in one file from the google earth api?
explanation:
im having a few polygones and i want to save them to sql server/kml file for the option to load it again in the future.
any ideas?
i'm using IE and cannot generate file to download.
thank you!